# UITabBarController - simulate double tap on UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a `UITabBarController`, if I push to different views from the first `UITabBarItem` and I tap the first `UITabBar` two times then the views that were pushed are popped back.

How can I simulate this exact functionality programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method of your `UITabBarController` to do this. You can manually count the number of taps on your `UITabBar` in the `AppDelegate`, and have certain conditions in the method.

For example, you could try in the .h file having an instance variable which stores the last `UIViewController` selected, and the time it was selected. If you then check the last time the `UIViewController` was called in same method, and it was a short enough period, then it would count as a double tap.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this without using `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`.